# Wolfram Technologies Workshop -- Slovenia

Tags: discussion

Out of curiosity (and since it's just across the street) I'll attend the [Wolfram Technologies Workshop - Slovenia](http://www.wolfram.com/events/slovenia-june-2014/).

This is probably a micro (nano?) event compared to the Wolfram technology Conference, but if there is interest I volunteer distribute some promotional material for the MMA.SE site.

Comment: Sounds like a good idea, Ajasja! I'm not sure how you'd get hold of such swag, but perhaps the Community Development Team can help. I can find out for you, if you like.

Comment: @Verbeia Great, thanks.

Comment: For swag, this [form](https://docs.google.com/a/stackoverflow.com/spreadsheet/viewform?awesm=s.tk_swagrequest&hl=en_US&formkey=dEcyWUtPck52Vnd3N01KbWRxLVdsQVE6MQ) could be useful, which is linked from this question: [How can I get Stack Exchange to send me to a conference?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/132282)

Comment: @YvesKlett That link you posted is the right way to go. That's where the community team would have directed folks. :)